# Number of connections handled by singleton object of Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have three node Cassandra cluster which is serving currently 50 writes/sec. Now, It would be 100 writes/sec and following are the details of my cluster :

**Keyspace definition :**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspacename WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 3 };
```

**Partitioner :**

```
 org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
```

I have client in c# (datastax c# driver) and i am using the singleton design pattern or rather creating only one object of cassandra server. Which will be used for writing and reading the data from ring. And reason for doing it was tcp connections were not getting closed on ring. Till now my ring is working fine and it is able to sustain the load of 50 writes/sec. Now it would increase to 100 writes/sec. 
So, my question is will the same design pattern would be able to handle the same given the configuration of my ring?

**C# code :**

```
public static ISession GetSingleton()
            {
                if (_singleton == null)
                {
                    Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cassandraCluster"].ToString().Split(',')).Build();
                    ISession session = cluster.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cassandraKeySpace"].ToString());
                    _singleton = session;
                }
                return _singleton;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the Cassandra side, 100 writes/sec is quite low. It would handle it easily.

From the client side, I see no problem with your design. According to me, it is a good idea to use Singleton pattern. But I cannot give you an exact answer since I do not know :

- What the size of your written data is.
- How performant your network is.
- Whether you use synchronous or asynchronous execution.

Generaly, we can reasonably consider 10 ms/writes. With synchronous execution, you would be able to write 100 times/sec. But you could not go along indefinitely because the driver would not create more connections.

In the other hand, you can use *ExecuteAsync* method to execute writes asynchronously. The C# Cassandra driver will manage the connection pool for you.

Another tip I can give you is [*PreparedStatement*](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientBoundStatements_t.html).

Comment: how does the PreparedStatement help in increasing the number of writes. Also, going to this documentation it suggest only one session instance would do per application. Since session itself creates multiple connections. why is it so?   http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientAddSession_t.html

Comment: PreparedStatement are parsed once and for all. It is a consequent amount of time to save. That's why it will help you in increasing the number of writes per second. About the session, asynchronous means you can execute multiple queries in parrallel. That's why the session needs to create multiple connections. You can refer to [Datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/asynchronousStatementExecution.html).